# Reading a particular page from a PDF document using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

How do I read a particular page (given a page number) from a PDF document using PDFBox?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "read"?

Comment: @Adrian: Say, I want the page #2 in `PDPage` object.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This should work:

```
PDPage firstPage = (PDPage)doc.getAllPages().get( 0 );
```

as seen in the [BookMark section of the tutorial](http://pdfbox.apache.org/userguide/bookmarks.html)

**Update 2015, Version 2.0.0 SNAPSHOT**

Seems this was removed and put back (?). *getPage* is in the 2.0.0 [javadoc](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html#getPage%28int%29). To use it:

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(filename));
PDPage doc = document.getPage(0);
```

The *getAllPages* method has been renamed *[getPages](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html#getPages%28%29)*

```
PDPage page = (PDPage)doc.getPages().get( 0 );
```

Comment: What is the type of `doc` here? The `PDDocument` class doesn't seem to have a `getAllPages` method.

Comment: @missingfaktor `doc` is a [PDDocumentCatalog](http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocumentCatalog.html) object

Comment: For those coming along here later: http://pdfbox.apache.org/cookbook/textextraction.html
Basically -- use PDFTextStripper, not PDPage as PDPage seems to be more about displaying a page on screen than getting text http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563482/read-text-from-a-particular-page-using-pdfbox#answer-15689797

Comment: For pdfbox 2.0 I simply used: pdDoc.getPage(pageNumber); where pdDoc is a type of PDDocument.

Comment: For PDFBox 1.8.10 there seems to be no method getAllPages() for the PDDocument type. The link does not work any more unfortunately.

Answer (score 20):

```
//Using PDFBox library available from http://pdfbox.apache.org/  
//Writes pdf document of specific pages as a new pdf file

//Reads in pdf document  
PDDocument pdDoc = PDDocument.load(file);

//Creates a new pdf document  
PDDocument document = null;

//Adds specific page "i" where "i" is the page number and then saves the new pdf document   
try {   
    document = new PDDocument();   
    document.addPage((PDPage) pdDoc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(i));   
    document.save("file path"+"new document title"+".pdf");  
    document.close();  
}catch(Exception e){}
```

Answer (score 4):

Thought I would add my answer here as I found the above answers useful but not exactly what I needed.

In my scenario I wanted to scan each page individually, look for a keyword, if that keyword appeared, then do something with that page (ie copy or ignore it).

I've tried to simply and replace common variables etc in my answer:

```
public void extractImages() throws Exception {
        try {
            String destinationDir = "OUTPUT DIR GOES HERE";
            // Load the pdf
            String inputPdf = "INPUT PDF DIR GOES HERE";
            document = PDDocument.load( inputPdf);
            List<PDPage> list = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
            // Declare output fileName
            String fileName = "output.pdf";
            // Create output file
            PDDocument newDocument = new PDDocument();
            // Create PDFTextStripper - used for searching the page string
            PDFTextStripper textStripper=new PDFTextStripper(); 
            // Declare "pages" and "found" variable
            String pages= null; 
            boolean found = false;     
            // Loop through each page and search for "SEARCH STRING". If this doesn't exist
            // ie is the image page, then copy into the new output.pdf. 
            for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                // Set textStripper to search one page at a time 
                textStripper.setStartPage(i); 
                textStripper.setEndPage(i);             
                PDPage returnPage = null;
                // Fetch page text and insert into "pages" string
                pages = textStripper.getText(document); 
                found = pages.contains("SEARCH STRING");
                    if (i != 0) {
                            // if nothing is found, then copy the page across to new                     output pdf file
                        if (found == false) {
                            returnPage = list.get(i - 1); 
                            System.out.println("page returned is: " + returnPage);
                            System.out.println("Copy page");
                            newDocument.importPage(returnPage);
                        }
                    }
            }    
            newDocument.save(destinationDir + fileName);

            System.out.println(fileName + " saved");
         } 
         catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             System.out.println("catch extract image");
         }
    }
```

Comment: Personal preference, but I find "if (! found)" to be much more readable than the "if (found == false)" syntax :)

Answer (score 1):

you can you getPage method over PDDocument instance

```
PDDocument pdDocument=null;
pdDocument = PDDocument.load(inputStream);
PDPage pdPage = pdDocument.getPage(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution. Hope it will solve your issue.

```
string fileName="C:\mypdf.pdf";
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(fileName);                   
PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
stripper.setStartPage(1);
stripper.setEndPage(2);
//above page number 1 to 2 will be parsed. for parsing only one page set both value same (ex:setStartPage(1);  setEndPage(1);)
string reslut = stripper.getText(doc);

doc.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the command-line call:

```
ExtractText -startPage 1 -endPage 1 filename.pdf
```

Change 1 to the page number that you need.

Comment: I have to do it thru a program.