# read text from a particular page using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I know how to read text of an entire pdf file usinf PDFBox using `PDFTextStripper.getText(PDDocument)`.

I also have a sample on how to get an object reference to a particular page using `PDDocumentCatalog.getAllPages().get(i)`.

How do I get the text of just one page using PDFBox as I dont see any such method on `PDPage` class?

Answer (score 37):

You can set parameters on the [`PDFTextStripper`](http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/util/PDFTextStripper.html) to read particular pages:

```
PDDocument doc; // document
int i; // page no.

PDFTextStripper reader = new PDFTextStripper();
reader.setStartPage(i);
reader.setEndPage(i);
String pageText = reader.getText(doc);
```

As far as I'm aware, [`PDPage`](http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDPage.html) is more used with representing a page onscreen, rather than extracting text. As such, I wouldn't recommend using this to extract text.