# How to read first few pages of a PDF file using TIKA

Tags: java, pdf, apache-tika

I am currently using the below code to extract the content and metadata of PDF files using TIKA library. Is there a way to read specific page OR limit the parsing to first few pages in TIKA?

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException,TikaException, SAXException {

      BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
      Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
      FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(new File("test/test.pdf"));
      ParseContext pcontext = new ParseContext();

      //parsing the document using PDF parser
      AutoDetectParser pdfparser = new AutoDetectParser(); 
      pdfparser.parse(inputstream, handler, metadata,pcontext);

      //getting the content of the document
      System.out.println("Contents of the PDF :" + handler.toString());

      //getting metadata of the document
      //System.out.println("Metadata of the PDF:");
      String[] metadataNames = metadata.names();
      System.out.println(metadata.get("xmpTPg:NPages"));

      for(String name : metadataNames) {
         System.out.println(name+ " : " + metadata.get(name));
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

TIKA doesn't really handle pages, but it does send `<div><p>` before and `</p></div>` after pages. You can edit your handler's `startElement` and `endElement` to search for these characters.

If you need more info, you can check out `topchef`'s answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6271696/2197529