# How to read PDF/DOCX page by page using tika library in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, docx, tika-python

```
`# #!/usr/bin/env python
import tika
tika.initVM()
from tika import parser

parsed = parser.from_file('frank_diary.docx')
print(parsed["metadata"])
print(parsed["content"])`
```

From this code i am able to read whole file but not page by page.

[Ref.](https://github.com/chrismattmann/tika-python/issues/191) I go through this reference but it's not working.
Is there any way to read PDF/DOCX using tike page by page?

I expect to read PDF/DOCX using tika page by page.

Example:
Dict = [{"page_number" : 1, "content":"content"},{"page_number" : 2, "content":"content"},{"page_number" : 3, "content":"content"}]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53093531/python-apache-tika-single-page-parser gives an example. https://github.com/chrismattmann/tika-python/issues/191